# Void convert to Boolean

Tags: java

[image: Error Screenshot]

```
private void btn_SearchActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

    if(rb_AccountNo.setSelected(true))
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: I **think** you want `if(rb_AccountNo.isSelected())` - calling `setSelected(true)` doesn't return anything.

Comment: Search about the return type of .setSelected first...

Comment: @elliott-frisch , i want when i clicked button  if(rb_AccountNo.setSelected(true))
    {
             lable.setText("My New");
    }

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, your method name is misleading, so you can change it to `isSelected` and secondly make its type boolean rather than void. Example: `boolean isSelected(){}`.